# Why does the /i option not work with the xcopy command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to use Xcopy to copy files and folders to a destination, whereby I am trying to append a date to the destination folder.

Here, I want cmd to assume that the destination is a folder, and not a file. So I used the /i option with the command. Yet, when I execute this code, cmd asks me if the destination is a file or a folder.

Here's a sample of my code. What am I doing wrong?

Note: Since my windows language is German, my date gets outputted in the "dd.mm.yyyy" format.

```
@echo on
Title xbackup.bat

REM -------------------------- Enter Source Directory --------------------------

set "dir1=C:\Users\ANUKRIS\Desktop\Process Folder"
REM Get Today's date
set datestamp=%date%

REM -------------------------- Enter Dest Directory --------------------------

set dir2=P:\_Departments\DGSB_FAO_G\09_Robotics\UIPath\Daimler_239_Obligo_Bereinigung\Backups\%datestamp%
xcopy "%dir1%" "%dir2%" /s /y /d /i
:end
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: Might I suggest using *anything* other than batch scripting? You can just wait for somebody to e.g. install it on a computer that can, say, display time normally. I use CygWin / bash scripting myself.

Comment: Please understand that the `%DATE%` variable will in many locales, individual user settings, or PC's contain characters which are disallowed for use in file or directory names. If this could be a problem in your specific case, I'd suggest that you search this site for solutions retrieving the date in a more robust way. I would also advise you to read the help information for the `RoboCopy` command, _(which superseded `XCopy` several Operating Systems ago)_.

Comment: Thank you @Compo. Absolutely valid point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell `xcopy` explicitly to use the destination as a folder, by just adding a `\` at the end:

```
xcopy "%dir1%" "%dir2%\" /s /y /d /i
```